# IE, Firefox and Chrome show different themes of audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, browser

IE, Firefox and Chrome show different themes of audio tag. This is what they show:

## Internet Explorer

[image]

## Firefox

[image]

## Chrome

[image]

What can I do to make them to use the same theme?

Comment: _Create your own_ And play with HTML5 media events and methods...

Comment: @Rayon My website is based on Drupal. I can't use my own. The players are using audio tag

Comment: You can create custom design for your player using `CSS` and attach events using `JavaScript`..

Comment: Refer http://authenticstyle.co.uk/html5-audio-player/ __or__ http://www.alexkatz.me/html5-audio/building-a-custom-html5-audio-player-with-javascript/

Comment: @Rayon thank you . I did that and it worked