# HTML5 <audio> tag reset

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there some css reset or other way to normalize the HTML5 `<audio>` tag and its controls so that the audio player it creates looks similar or the same in all browsers? Or is there perhaps another way to create a normalized audio player (without starting from scratch)?

NOTE: the specific audio player I want is a simple toolbar with a progress bar and play button and a pause button.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38094011/ie-firefox-and-chrome-show-different-themes-of-audio-tag#comment63635799_38094011

Answer (score 1):

Each browser interprets the audio player in its own way. There is no standard design. But you can use some framework css or some flash player (if you want it to look the same in all browsers). I recommend using css option because flash will fall.

https://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-html5-audio-players/

Another option is to host your audio in some external service like soundcloud, they offer an audio player that you can insert into your website and your player looks the same on any browser. I hope I could help.

Luck.

Comment: Thank you so much!! The soundcloud player sounds like an excellent option and one i've never heard before